# Does noun + くらいなら have the same nuance as verb + くらいなら?

Tags: sentence, particle-くらい

[image]

多少の貸しくらいならあっさり相殺されるくらい大きな借りが

In the first line the character says that he has a debt toward him, so no 礼 will be necessary.

Then in the second line he adds I assume the nature of his 借り.

I understand as far "あっさり相殺されるくらい大きな借りが" goes he's saying that his debt is big enough that they'd off set each other.

多少の貸しくらいなら

My reading would be like "If it's something like a small loan" but くらいなら also means "rather than x"

Answer (score 2):

- 借り refers to mental debts the speaker owes someone, and 貸し is the opposite of it, something the listener owes the speaker. See: [Meaning of 貸し and 借り in「この貸しは借りになることなく相殺もしない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94490/5010)
- `noun + くらい` always means "something (trivial) like ～". `dictionary-form + くらいなら` [sometimes means "rather than ～"](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-kurai-nara-meaning/), but it has nothing to do with this sentence.
- なら is basically "if", but it's used like an emphatic topic marker here. See: [Usage of なら in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/89097/5010)

> 遺憾ながら私もあなたに借りがあるのですよ。
> I must admit, I also owe you one.
>
> **多少の貸しくらい**[なら]{(は)}あっさり相殺されるくらい大きな借りが(あるのです)。
> There is such a large debt I owe you that **any minor debt you might have towards me** would be easily offset.
> I owe you so much that **any small amount you owe me** would be easily cancelled out.